# how to avoid null pointer exception in selenium webdriver java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, cucumber

I added a new feature file(TestElement.feature) to test the existence of graphic elements, I wanted to start by checking if logo (image) exists.

This is my project explorer :

[image]

the file is a continuation of the first test because after the login he finds the home page of the application.

my feature file :

```
Feature: TestElement
    
    Scenario Outline: Vérifier la connexion avec le compte e-bureau
Given l utilisateur est sur la page de Guardian qualification "https://self.sso-dev.infra.ftgroup/logingassifaible.jsp?activateWindows=true&TYPE=33554433&REALMOID=06-000ad14a-2fb1-1b71-8d9e-e8be0aaad064&GUID=&SMAUTHREASON=0&METHOD=GET&SMAGENTNAME=$SM$xbSpBfm%2bhWHxeQBK%2fUVaOtTlaTiephGDVWxzokSFrQp9WFGjEVlALHaS6jL5m5xG&TARGET=$SM$HTTPS%3a%2f%2fself%2esso-dev%2einfra%2eftgroup%2fAuthForm%2fredirect%2ejsp%3fRETURN%3dhttps$%3A$%2F$%2Fself%2esso-dev%2einfra%2eftgroup$%2FAuthForm$%2Fredirect%2ejsp$%3FRETURN$%3D"
When l utilisateur entre son cuid "TLFJ9022"
And l utilisateur entre son mot de passe "Touria@1998"
And l utilisateur clique sur le button valider
And l utilisateur clique import de masse Gimili-Recette
And l utilisateur choisi le referentiel

        
    Scenario: Vérifier les élements graphique de la page d acceuil
    Given verifier le logo 
    Then checker les elements de la nav-bar
```

the file LoginGuardianDef :

```
public class LoginGuardianDef {
public WebDriver driver;
public LoginGuardian lg;
public GuardianHome gh;
public MageReferentiel mr;
public TestGraphicElement tg;
//JavascriptExecutor executor;

@Given("l utilisateur est sur la page de Guardian qualification {string}")
public void l_utilisateur_est_sur_la_page_de_guardian_qualification(String url) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\driver\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    
    lg= new LoginGuardian(driver);
    gh = new GuardianHome(driver);
    mr = new MageReferentiel(driver);
    tg = new TestGraphicElement(driver);
    
    driver.get(url);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    //this.executor = (JavascriptExecutor)this.driver;
}

@When("l utilisateur entre son cuid {string}")
public void l_utilisateur_entre_son_cuid(String cuid) throws Exception {
    lg.setCuid(cuid);
    Thread.sleep(3000);
}

@When("l utilisateur entre son mot de passe {string}")
public void l_utilisateur_entre_son_mot_de_passe(String mdp) throws Exception {
    lg.setMdp(mdp);
    Thread.sleep(3000);
}

@When("l utilisateur clique sur le button valider")
public void l_utilisateur_clique_sur_le_button_valider() throws Exception {
    lg.clickVerifierForm();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
}
@When("l utilisateur clique import de masse Gimili-Recette")
public void l_utilisateur_clique_import_de_masse_gimili_recette() throws Exception {
    gh.clickAccesToMage();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
}
@When("l utilisateur choisi le referentiel")
public void l_utilisateur_choisi_le_referentiel() throws Exception {
        //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        //mr.scrollDown();
        mr.clickConnexion();
        //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        //executor.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,document.body.scrollHeight);");
        
        //JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        //WebElement h5 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h5[contains(text(),'Import de mails en GED')]"));
        //js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", h5);
    
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    
        
    }
```

}

and the file GraphicTestDef(i did 60000 ms because the application take 1min to load):

```
public class GraphicTestDef {

public TestGraphicElement tg;


@Given("verifier le logo Orange")
public void verifier_le_logo_orange() {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new io.cucumber.java.PendingException();
}

@Then("checker les elements de la nav-bar")
public void checker_les_elements_de_la_nav_bar(io.cucumber.datatable.DataTable dataTable) {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    // For automatic transformation, change DataTable to one of
    // E, List<E>, List<List<E>>, List<Map<K,V>>, Map<K,V> or
    // Map<K, List<V>>. E,K,V must be a String, Integer, Float,
    // Double, Byte, Short, Long, BigInteger or BigDecimal.
    //
    // For other transformations you can register a DataTableType.
    throw new io.cucumber.java.PendingException();
}
```

}

and my page object is :

```
public class TestGraphicElement {
WebDriver webdriver;
JavascriptExecutor executor;

public TestGraphicElement(WebDriver rwebDriver) {
    webdriver = rwebDriver;
    this.executor = (JavascriptExecutor)this.webdriver;
    PageFactory.initElements(webdriver, this);
}

public void checkHomePage() {
    boolean status = webdriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"headerLogo\"]")).isDisplayed();
    Assert.assertEquals(true, status);
    
    
}
```

}

i have this error :
[image]

Comment: Why are creating instance for `TestGraphicElement` in `GraphicTestDef` class?

Comment: for the definition step , is this not the right way ?

Comment: What is the purpose of `TestGraphicElement`  in `GraphicTestDef`? You are not using that in that class. If you are not using `public TestGraphicElement tg;` in `GraphicTestDef` class then remove it and try. Else if you are using then initialize and pass the driver.